# Why [array].concat() and [array].concat.apply() gives different output ?

Tags: javascript

The code below,

```
console.log([].concat.apply([2],[[99],5,6,[2,3]]));
```

outputs

```
[ 2, 99, 5, 6, 2, 3 ]
```

And the code below,

```
console.log([2].concat([99]).concat([5,6,[2,3]]));
```

outputs

```
[ 2, 99, 5, 6, [ 2, 3 ] ]
```

My assumption was that the output of

```
console.log([].concat.apply([2],[[99],5,6,[2,3]]));
```

Should be

```
[2,[99],5,6,[2,3]]
```

But its not, why ?

Comment: Seems like `apply` recurses each argument while the value is an array. But I'd like some more in depth proof too.

Comment: You are missing another  pair of brackets  around the apply  input for both statements to be equivalent.

Comment: Hey @Guedes, no its not the issue with apply. Check this code:function abc(x,y,z){console.log(x,y,z);}. Here abc.apply(this, [3,4,[5]]) yields 3 4 [5] whereas  abc.apply(this, [3,4,5]) yields 3 4 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is concat + apply doing to flatten an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351817/what-exactly-is-concat-apply-doing-to-flatten-an-array)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because:

```
console.log( [].concat.apply([2],[[99],5,6,[2,3]]) );
```

is equivalent to:

```
console.log( [2].concat([99], 5, 6, [2,3]) );
```

`.concat` takes the multiple arguments, and merges all the arrays (and non-array arguments) into a single array. Basically, the array arguments get unpacked 1 level.

To get that output, you would have to wrap each of the array elements in an additional array.

```
console.log( [].concat.apply([2],[[[99]],5,6,[[2,3]]]) );
```

Perhaps you would prefer to use a `.push` based approach.

```js
var a = [2];
a.push.apply(a, [[99],5,6,[2,3]]);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your assuming about in a way without seeing the [document](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.4). See, the actual syntax for concat is,

```
Array.prototype.concat ( [ item1 [ , item2 [ , … ] ] ] )
```

So your code is barely equals to,

```
[].concat.apply([itm1], [itm2,itm3,itm4]...)
```

From your code's point of view, your code is similar to,

```
[2].concat([99],5,6,[2,3]);
```

let's dismantle your code,

```
console.log([].concat.apply([2],[[99],5,6,[2,3]]));
// 1. apply will call the function by applying the parameter supplied as an array.
// 2. so the first parameter for apply would be this for that function
// 3. and the second parameter for it would be the arguments in an array form.
// 4. Hence internally apply will call the function concat as,
//    [2].concat([99],5,6,[2,3]); //[2] will be 'this'
```

But for your requirement, you don't need to go with `apply`, you can use `call`.

```
console.log([].concat.call([2],[[99],5,6,[2,3]]));
//[2,[99],5,6,[2,3]]
```

Comment: concat.call and concat gave the same results for me??

Answer (score 1):

Note, `apply` effectively is a ***spread*** operator for the second argument.  so

#### The same result:

```
console.log([].concat.apply([2],[[99],5,6,[2,3]]));


console.log([2].concat(...[[99],5,6,[2,3]])); // * using es6 spread operator `...`


console.log([2].concat([99],5,6,[2,3]));
```

#### which is different from:

```
console.log([2].concat([[99],5,6,[2,3]]));
```

The difference being the spread.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [concat MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), you would find the syntax for Array.prototype.concat is

```
var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])
```

and not just values.**Arrays and/or values** to concatenate into a new array

So `[].concat.apply([],[2,3,[6,4]])` is equal to `[].concat.apply([],[2,3,6,4])`.