# What exactly is concat + apply doing to flatten an array?

Tags: javascript

I've basically memorized this `[].concat.apply([], a)` to flatten an array that isn't deeply nested but I don't entirely understand how it works.  For instance, where does `apply` comes into this?

Is it more efficient than `arr.reduce((x,y) => [...x,...y])` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of aspects to this:

`concat` flattens (to one level) arrays you pass into it, including only their elements in the resulting array:

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].concat(4, 5, [6, 7, 8]));
```

Notice how the array at the end was flattened.

The `apply` is `Function.prototype.apply`: You can use it to call a function specifying what `this` should be and providing the arguments for the function as an array. That last bit is critical: The array's elements are passed to `concat` as discrete arguments, and if any of *those* are arrays, `concat` extracts their content. So

```
let a = [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, [6, 7, 8]];
a = [].concat.apply([], a);
//  ^^--- (1)       ^^--- (2)
```

...calls `concat` with `this` being array (2) above, passing in the arguments `[1, 2, 3]`, `4`, `5`, and `[6, 7, 8]`. (Array (1) is only used to get `concat`, then thrown away.)

`[].concat.apply([], a)` is a bit wasteful (it creates two throw-away arrays, both of the ones indicated above), though it's not likely to matter; really it should be `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], although that still creates and throws away one of them. (Obviously, you'd tuck that away in a reusable function so you don't have to type that out every time.)

But in modern JavaScript you may want to use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) instead, with a polyfill if necessary:

```js
console.log(
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    4, 5,
    [6, 7, 8]
  ].flat()
);
```

The above works on up-to-date versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but again you can use a polyfill to use it on other browsers.

Note that `flat` optionally does *recursive* flattening. By default it does just one level (like `concat`), but if you specify a *depth* argument, you can go deeper (you can use Infinity to handle all levels).

Comment: this was exceptionally explained @T.J.Crowder , thank you.

Comment: this behavior of `concat` is very confusing!

Comment: @dashesy - Big time. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The `apply` call is equivalent to using spread syntax:

```
[].concat.apply([], a)
[].concat(...a)
```

It simply concatenates an empty array with all the values of `a`, passing multiple arguments to [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). It constructs a new array in a single step, which is more efficient than your `reduce` solution that creates lots of intermediate results.