# how does this concat command work with this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply

I came across this JS problem but I can't figure out the syntax of how it's working, could someone please help to explain? I don't understand the empty square bracket syntax at the start and then how the concat is being applied with another empty square bracket? it's just quite confusing for me.

Appreciate any help to step through this.

```
let arr = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]];

let flattened = [].concat.apply([], arr);
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is concat + apply doing to flatten an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351817/what-exactly-is-concat-apply-doing-to-flatten-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]];

let flattened = [].concat.apply([], arr);
*first array*---|                |---*second array*
```

The `first` array has one goal:

- to invoke `concat()` method with `this`. Here `this` is the `second` array. Then the `first` array is thrown away

Then `apply()` method flattens the `arr` array to one level.
You can check it:

```js
let foo = [0].concat([1,2,3], [[1,2,3]] ); 
console.log(foo)
```

**UPDATE:**

In addition, the first array can be removed:

```js
const arr = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]];

const flattened = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr);
console.log(flattened)
```

**Some info how `apply()` works.**

In addition, it would be really useful to know how `apply()` flattens array items to one level or how `apply()` takes an array of arguments and treats each element of that array as a single argument.

Let me show a simple example. We have the following object and method:

```js
const showFullName = (arg_1, arg_2) => {
    console.log(`arg_1 is ${arg_1}`);
    console.log(`arg_2 is ${arg_2}`);
}

let foo = {};
showFullName.apply(foo, ['firstName', 'surname']);
```

Comment: thanks @StepUp what is the point of the empty array in the apply function then? I know it's meant to reference a 'this' object but there is no 'this' object in this case is there? I'm confused by the 2 sets of empty square brackets still if you can explain more please.

Comment: Thanks @StepUp so if I understand correctly the first [] are basically ignored after invoking concat and then it's the second set of [] which are basically being used to concat each argument? So you would always need that second set of [] and you couldn't use null or something.

Comment: @jobe please, see my updated answer about your question of first array. The second question might be answered like this:  You can use any type that you want as this will be context. This is how `apply()` works. However, then `concat` method will handle it as an argument and will put it into flattened array. Try to test it `console.log(Array.prototype.concat.apply({foo: 'bar'}, arr));`

Comment: Thanks @StepUp I accepted your answer. So the [] of the first array was kind of like a shorthand for Array.prototype? is that right?

Comment: I did try your test by the way and it's interesting that it places an object or boolean as the first element in the array but with [], it doesn't keep an empty element as item 0 in the flattened array?

Comment: @jobe `So the [] of the first array was kind of like a shorthand for Array.prototype?` yeah

Comment: @jobe ` it doesn't keep an empty element as item 0 in the flattened array` it looks like empty array does not have `0`

Answer (score 0):

The [] is an empty array. The concat function concatenate two or more arrays: `[].concat(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])`

The catch here is to know how apply works. The second parameter of apply is an array of parameters. It's like doing this (if you're familiar with the concept of desctructuring):
`[].concat(...arr)`

You can read more about apply [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)